# If the prefix in the AWS lifecycle rules is 'data/' does the rule apply to file named data.<extension>?

Tags: amazon-s3

Question regarding lifecycle rules in AWS:

If the prefix in the AWS lifecycle rules is data/ does the rule apply to file named data. or data/file. ?

Thank you.

I am new to AWS and this is my first time trying to create the lifecycle rule.

Answer (score 0):

- Life cycle rules will be only applied what comes under prefix nothing else.
- if inside "data/" you have a file named data.txt or anything else, life cycle rule will be applied.
- but not outside or in the same directory like shown below.
  [image]
- If you upload any file that contains '/' in the name it will be converted to colon ':' when you select file from aws console.
  like this

[image]

Comment: *"If you upload any file that contains '/' in the name it will be converted to colon ':' when you select file from aws console. like this"* I'm not sure what you did to cause this, but saying it is caused by uploading a file with `/` in the name can't be accurate.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, if in side data/ folder I have files temp.txt, tem1.txt etc.. this considers only these files inside the folder data\ and ignore anything outside this. Am I correct ??

Comment: Yes Correct, It consider only what's inside.